# XPC causes crash dialog to appear

Tags: macos, cocoa, xpc

I implemented XPC as Apple reccomends it for high risk operations. The problem is that when XPC crashes it displays crash dialog to the user. I know that this code can sometimes crach, that is why I mplemented XPC in the first place. So is there any way I can suppress the crash report?

If you need any details please add comment, I will update the thread ASAP.

Comment: What is causing the crash?  Is it an `NSException` or a signal?

Comment: Exception can be caught so that is not a problem, it is caused by signal. We also tried to capture the signals but well, it simply doesn't work for our XPC.

Comment: So you have code that you know can _crash_ sometimes? Is the crash your fault or the fault of a buggy Cocoa class/framework?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it uses dynamic libs that we are not the athours of. Also it is dealing with file content reading from users and there can be literally anything there.

Comment: I see, but crashing is still a Very Bad Thing (tm). What exactly causes the crash? XPC was - to my knowledge - created to separate different permissions/entitlements but not so that we don't have to care about code crashing. I'd strongly suggest trying to prevent the code from crashing at all costs.

Comment: Yes I totally agree. I am pretty sure in most cases it is bad memory access, like freeing memory and then trying to access it or other things of that kind. I know it sounds really bad.

Comment: I am also aware there might be no answer to this. Just posted a question because maybe somebody got this figured out.

Comment: When the crash happens, XPC client i.e. the main app should be notified of the problem and provide a better report or even a fix. Sure thing, we should avoid crashes, but XPC services are designed perfectly to move all crashes into helper processes. So I agree with a topic starter: crash dialog should not appear, especially because the main app is still running.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Sep/msg01658.html

That might solve your problem, but it might cause other problems: I'm not sure if this is still permitted in sandboxed apps...

Still, the Right Thing to do is to fix the crashes :)

Comment: Sounds very good, we will test it for while but that should be it.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help :) Accepting the answer is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah but so far it is also not working for our XPC :) but I will give it some more try over the weekend, I have some ideas